# Expresión regular para sustituir <br><br> por <p></p>

Tags: javascript, html, regex, dom

Buenas.
Estoy intentando hacer algo de manera que cada 2 <br> seguidos se conviertan en un <p></p>

He conseguido hacer que solo una vez se convierta de <br><br> a <p></p>.
Pero cuando intento meter 2 <p> seguidos no se crean más parrafos.

Otra cosa es que estoy metiendo el texto que saco de las sustituciiones directamente en elemento.innerHTML. Lo que pasa es que tambien si escribo directamente elementos en el TEXTAREA estos se añaden. Hay también alguna manera de codificar este HTML despues de recibir el texto?
Cual sería la mejor manera de hacer todo esto que quiero hacer?

El codigo de ejemplo sería el siguiente. Si tengo el siguiente código HTML:

```
<p>
  Esto es un texto
  <br><br>Parrafo 1
  <br><br>Parrafo 2
  <br><br>Parrafo3
</p>
```

Se convierta en:

```
<p>
  <p>Parrafo 1</p>
  <p>Parrafo 2</p>
  <p>Parrafo 3</p>
</p>
```

Y partiendo del anterior codigo me gustaría poder hacer que dentro de cada parrafo cuando haga lo siguiente:

```
<p>
  <p>Parrafo 1 <br><br>Nuevo parrafo</p>
  <p>Parrafo 2</p>
  <p>Parrafo 3<br><br>Subparrafo de 3</p>
</p>
```

Se convierta en:

```
<p>
  <p>Parrafo 1</p>
  <p>Nuevo parrafo</p>
  <p>Parrafo 2</p>
  <p>Parrafo 3</p>
  <p>Subparrafo de 3</p>
</p>
```

O que esos 2 parrafos vayan al final en vez de ir justo despues del parrafo donde estaba metidos sus

Como he dicho he conseguido crear 2 parrafos seguidos con su texto interno, pero al crear el tercero se me crean 2 BR con un texto dentro de uno de esos 2 parrafos.
Luego cambié la expresión regular y ahora solo consigo que se cree 1 parrafo seguido.

En fin, no consigo dar con la expresión regular, si es que es posible.
Aquí el HTML y el javascript

HTML

```
<div>
    <h4>Escribe un texto cualquiera</h4>
    <textarea cols="60" rows="10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In, id, quidem ex quaerat dignissimos saepe molestias vero praesentium nostrum iste libero voluptatem quam maxime quos quod obcaecati quae dolor pariatur!</textarea>

    <p id="p1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In, id, quidem ex quaerat dignissimos saepe molestias vero praesentium nostrum iste libero voluptatem quam maxime quos quod obcaecati quae dolor pariatur!</p>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
window.onload = function(){
  const p1 = document.querySelector("#p1");
  const textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");

  textarea.addEventListener("input", function(){
    let texto = this.value.replace(/\n/gi, "<br>");
    texto = texto.replace(/(.*<p>.*)*(?:<br(?:\s\/)?>){2}(.*)(<\/p>)*/gi, "$1$3<p>$2</p>");

    texto = texto.replace(/-{4,8}/g, "<hr>");

    p1.innerHTML = texto;

  });
}
```

Comment: Si bien se puede lograr con una expresión regular, no es la mejor herramienta para este objetivo. Para eso, te conviene usar el DOM de JavaScript y procesar cada elemento como corresponde. A menos que me digas que el textarea va a tener solamente texto análogo a tus ejemplos, siempre va a aparecer un ejemplo que rompa tu expresión regular

Comment: @Mariano Estaba experimentando, pero la idea no era hacer con el textarea algo muy complejo. Mi unica idea era lo del <br> y lo de la linea hr que aparece en el codigo. Pero no es mi intención permitir la creacion de elementos libremenete a través del textarea escribiendo los elementos como tal. Eso lo quería restringir pero no sé como.
La funcíon principal del textarea no iba a ser la de crear elementos.
Esto lo hacia solo con intención de formateo.
Por otro lado, si quisiera implementar una especie de formateador con botoes tendría que hacerlo con el manupulador de dom de javascript?

Comment: Cuando uno habla del DOM, está refiriéndose a las funciones que todos conocemos de JavaScript: `getElementsByTagName()`, `querySelectorAll()`, etc. En cuanto a lo de botones, depende de como quieras implementarlo, pero sí, me imagino que manipulando con el DOM y un poco de funciones de Strings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dejame contestarte primero a la pregunta de regex, pero avisándote que es la estrategia equivocada, sólo por tu comentario aclarando que es para estos casos sencillos.

Se puede hacer que coincida con todo el texto hasta que encuentre alguna de estas etiquetas: `<br><br>` o `</p>`. Es decir, la estrategia que te propongo es hacer una expresión regular que coincida con todo el texto fuera de una etiqueta...

```
[^<>\s][^<>]*`
```

... hasta que encuentre las etiquetas buscadas o el fin del texto.

```
[^<>\s][^<>]*(?:<(?:br\s*\/?>\s*<br\s*\/?|\/p[^>]*)>|$)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

La idea principal de esto es **capturar** el texto que nos interesa, y **consumir** las etiqueta previa y la etiqueta posterior.

[image: ESQUEMA DEL REGEX QUE ESTÁ MÁS ABAJO]

Como se ve, pusimos entre paréntesis todo lo que queremos que capture, para poder mantenerlo a la hora de realizar el reemplazo (con `$1`).

#### Expresión regular:

```
/(?:<p[^>]*>\s*)?([^<>\s][^<>]*)(?:<(?:br\s*\/?>\s*<br\s*\/?|\/p[^>]*)>(?:\s*\n)?|$)/gi
```

La función quedaría:

```js
window.onload = function(){
    const textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");

    textarea.addEventListener("input", formatearParrafos);

    //Formatear al inicio también (sólo para esta demo)
    formatearParrafos();
}

function formatearParrafos(elem){
    const textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");
    let texto = textarea.value;

    texto = texto.replace(
        /(?:<p[^>]*>\s*)?([^<>\s][^<>]*)(?:<(?:br\s*\/?>\s*<br\s*\/?|\/p[^>]*)>(?:\s*\n)?|$)/gi,
        "<p>$1</p>\n"
    );

    texto = texto.replace(/-{4,8}/g, "<hr>");

    const p1 = document.querySelector("#p1");
    //p1.innerHTML = texto;
    p1.innerText = texto;  //innerText para mostrarlo en un PRE
}
```

```html
<textarea cols="60" rows="5">
<p>
  <p>Parrafo 1 <br><br>Nuevo parrafo</p>
  <p>Parrafo 2</p>
  <p>Parrafo 3<br><br>Subparrafo de 3</p>
</p>
</textarea>

<pre id="p1"></pre>
```

Pero insisto, hay muchos casos que romperían este patrón, y realmente te recomendaría encararlo con DOM y realizar una nueva pregunta con lo que puedas avanzar.

Comment: Pillo la idea. Con la expresión que saqué solo me saca un nivel. Dentro de los siguientes <p> me crea solo <br>. Es como si no fuera capaz de meterse más adentro de las anidaciiones.
De todas formas creo que me he metido en algo imposible de hacer con expresiones regulares por lo que estoy viendo y según dices.
Mi intención era la de hacer el pequeño formateo a traves de simple escritura o sustituyendo algunas cosas. Como una manera de poder crear elementos sin codificar solo usando el teclado. Un <p> por alli, un <hr>, algun otro conjunto de caracteres por un caracter especial y cosas así

Comment: como esto pero que pillase todas las <br><br> dentro de más <p></p> era lo que buscaba, pero poniendo las nuevas <p> fuera del todo. texto = texto.replace(/(?:<br>\s*<br>)(.*)[^<br>]*(<\/p>.*)*/gi,"$2<p>$1</p>");

Comment: @Lorthas edité la respuesta para mejorar la expresión regular y que coincida con el tu ejemplo... es un poco más de detalle, aunque aún querría agregar más a la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Aunque la respuesta de arriba la elegí como la óptima, solo me gustaría añadir una opción que he descubierto haciendo pruebas.

Está probado tanto en Mozilla como en Vivaldi.

La función con la expresión regular quedaría así:

```
texto = texto.replace(/(<p>[^<\/>]*)*?(?:<br(?:[\S\s]*?\/)?>){2}/gi, "$1<p>") // Replace <br><br> with a <p> element.
```

Al no cerrar la etiqueta <p> en la sustitución, los navegadores la cierran automaticamente al insertar en innerHTML el HTML con la nueva sustitución.

Esto permite que al crear un nuevo parrafo se pueda seguir escribiendo dentro de el como si hubieramos movido el cursor dentro del parrafo. Se seguirá escribiendo en el nuevo parrafo hasta que volvamos a introducir 2 <br><br> consecutivos.

Asi el siguiente HTML en texto quedaría así al meterlo en un innerHTML ya habiendo sustituido los valores <br><br>

**Sin sustituir**

```
<p>
  Hola
  <br>
  Mundo
  <br>
  <br>
  Parrafo 1
  <br>
  Salto linea parrafo 1
  <br>
  <br>
  Parrafo 2
  <br>
  Salto linea parrafo 2
</p>
```

**Después de sustituir quedaría así:**

```
<p>
  Hola
  <br>
  Mundo
  <p>
    Parrafo 1
    <br>
    Salto de linea parrafo 1
  </p>
  <p>
    Parrafo 2
    <br>
    Salto linea parrafo 2
  </p>
</p>
```

Aunque buscar este comportamiento de no cerrar etiquetas para conseguir este objetivo y algun otro seguramente no sea el más indicado.